# startmanagingcursor() still needed?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am using cursorLoader in my app.

My question is I am still using startmanagingcursor(cursor);  method to manage my cursor in a particularactivity. Is this function still needed?

since this method is deprecated, may I know the exact alternative method.

Everyone said LoaderManager with Loader are the solution to my problem.

The real problem is I have implemented LoaderManager and Loader along with these below overridden methods:

```
    @Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0)
{
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor)
{
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor); 
}
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg1, Bundle instanceState)
{
    CursorLoader cursorLoader= new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), searchContentUri, null, selection, selecArgs, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

I wanna know that here where the query is being called?

Comment: if you are using cursor loaders and loader callbacks and getcontent providers to get the cursor , then u do not need startmanaging cursors since it is already handled bt the provider or loader callback

Comment: Is that necessary to replace NotifyingAsyncQueryHandler to execute query after switched into LoaderManager.?

Comment: i am not really sure about this, sorry .. just worked with the basics of cursor loaders and callbacks and content providers bt never called this method

Comment: This is my guess. AsyncQueryHandler uses ContentResolver to mine the database.  But here LoaderManager can do it directly.  So, when one uses LoaderManager, no need to use AsyncQueryHander to Handle query.